# Count unique values, ignore the spelling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a problem.  I have the following dataframe. I want to count all the unique values. As you can see the problem is, that some of the words are uppercase or lowercase but are compleately the same thing i want to count. So in my case "Wifi" and "wifi" should be counted as 2. Same for the others. Is there a way i can do that by for example ignore the upper and lower case? And as you can see there are different writings for wifi (for example "Wifi 230 mb/s") is there a way to count the wifis when wifi is in the string?

```py
d = {'host_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
     'value': ['Hot Water', 'Wifi', 'Kitchen',
               'Wifi', 'Hot Water',
               'Coffe Maker', 'wifi', 'hot Water', 'Wifi 230 mb/s']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df)


print(len(df[df['value'].str.contains("Wifi", case=False)]))
print(df['value'].unique())
print(len(df['value'].unique()))
```

```py
[out]
   host_id        value
0        1    Hot Water
1        1         Wifi
2        1      Kitchen
3        2         Wifi
4        2    Hot Water
5        3  Coffe Maker
6        3         wifi
7        3    hot Water
8        3    Wifi 230 mb/s

4 # count wifi

['Hot Water' 'Wifi' 'Kitchen' 'Coffe Maker' 'wifi' 'hot Water'] # unique values
6 # len unique values
```

What [out] should look like:

```py
        value     count
0   Hot Water         3
1        Wifi         4
2     Kitchen         1
3 Coffe Maker         1
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is problem only with `wifi` - possible another substrings use:

```
df['value'] = (df['value'].mask(df['value'].str.contains("Wifi", case=False), 'wifi')
                          .str.title())
print (df)
   host_id        value
0        1    Hot Water
1        1         Wifi
2        1      Kitchen
3        2         Wifi
4        2    Hot Water
5        3  Coffe Maker
6        3         Wifi
7        3    Hot Water
8        3         Wifi

print(df['value'].value_counts())
Wifi           4
Hot Water      3
Kitchen        1
Coffe Maker    1
Name: value, dtype: int64


print(df.groupby('value', sort=False).size().reset_index(name='count'))
         value  count
0    Hot Water      3
1         Wifi      4
2      Kitchen      1
3  Coffe Maker      1
```

EDIT:

```
#counts original values wit hconvert to uppercase first latters
s = df['value'].str.title().value_counts()
print (s)
Wifi             3
Hot Water        3
Wifi 230 Mb/S    1
Kitchen          1
Coffe Maker      1
Name: value, dtype: int64

#filter if counts greater like N
N = 2
good = s.index[s.gt(N)]       
print (good)
Index(['Wifi', 'Hot Water'], dtype='object')
```

---

```
#extract values by list good

import re

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in good)
df['new'] = df['value'].str.extract(rf'({pat})', expand=False, flags=re.I).str.title()
print (df)
   host_id          value        new
0        1      Hot Water  Hot Water
1        1           Wifi       Wifi
2        1        Kitchen        NaN
3        2           Wifi       Wifi
4        2      Hot Water  Hot Water
5        3    Coffe Maker        NaN
6        3           wifi       Wifi
7        3      hot Water  Hot Water
8        3  Wifi 230 mb/s       Wifi

df1 = df.groupby('new', sort=False).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
         new  count
0  Hot Water      3
1       Wifi      4


#get values not matched to good list (working if no NaNs in original column)    
df2 = df[df['new'].isna()].groupby('value', sort=False).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df2)
         value  count
0      Kitchen      1
1  Coffe Maker      1
```

If need both:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. The problem is that there is problem with also the other values and not only wifi.

Comment: @Test -  iwas worried aboit it. Is possible specified values for counts? How is possible identify `good substrings` for count and `bad substrings` for remove, replace to space?

Comment: For example you can see this line of code `(df.groupby('value', sort=False).size().reset_index(name='count')` this give us back the values, and lets say if a value is counted more than 3 time than it is good substrig. And all below sould be ignored.

Comment: @Test - answer was edited.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much that is perfect for my project. The cherry on the cake would be to write out the disselected values. So in that case we get for example a second list with the values which havent made it into the good substring. I would like the final count to include the values that are not taken into account by the substring.

Comment: What I mean `0    Hot Water      3
1         Wifi      4
2      Kitchen      1
3  Coffe Maker      1` but with your perfect code with the substrings

Comment: @Test - hmmm, finally are only 2 values, `Hot Water` and `Wifi`, so `Kitchen` and `Coffe` not possible processing.

Comment: @Test - answer was edited. with column `new` and counts.

Comment: Thank you!! That is what I want, but `df2` is empty when I run the code :(

Comment: @Test - hmm, not some typo?

Comment: `Empty DataFrame
Columns: [value, count]
Index: []` What I got, sorry for that. I copied every line of your code

Comment: @Test - in sample data? Do you use column `new` ? Is correct `new` and then `value` in `df2 = df[df['new'].isna()].groupby('value', sort=False).size().reset_index(name='count')` ?

Comment: For the short time i uploaded a picture of your code (see in the question). So you can see my outputs. Hope that helps !

Comment: @Test - Problem is in your code is necessary replace `df['value'] = df['value'].str.extract(rf'({pat})', expand=False, flags=re.I).str.title()` to `df['new'] = df['value'].str.extract(rf'({pat})', expand=False, flags=re.I).str.title()` - check `value` column has no NaNs like in your ouptut.

Answer (score -1):

Use `str.lower()` or `str.upper()` method on your list before comparing them. That should eliminate duplicates.
If you would like to eliminate typos or other similar strings you can use python-Levenshtein to calculate distance and set 'cut off point'
https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/

Comment: Thank you. And how could I count the `value`s?

Comment: This post will answer your question in details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item